# how to make filtered list of Api and implement pagination of infinite scrolling in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is working just for filter the page 1 but after  implementing  infinite scroll using react-infinite-scroll-component it does not append the page 2 results with page 1 by using spead operator it makes setcontacts an array of array   can any one hep me in this

```
const searchState =  (async fetchData => {
    const requests= await axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api url',
        params: { name: Search, page: page },
    });
    const cons= requests.data.results;
    console.log(cons);
    // console.log(cons.location222.name)
    let  matches = cons.filter(con => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`^${fetchData}`,'gi');

        return con.name.match(regex);
    });

    if (fetchData.length === 0) {
        matches=[];
    }

    // setLoading(true)
    setContacts(matches);

    // setContacts(prevcontacts=>{ return [...prevcontacts,matches]})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To load content infinitely using a React Component. I'm using ["React Infinite Scroller"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller). This fork maintains a simple, lightweight infinite scroll package that supports both window and scrollable elements.

Window scroll events

```
<InfiniteScroll
    pageStart={0}
    loadMore={loadFunc}
    hasMore={true || false}
    loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
>
    {items} // <-- This is the content you want to load
</InfiniteScroll>
```

DOM scroll events

```
<div style="height:700px;overflow:auto;">
    <InfiniteScroll
        pageStart={0}
        loadMore={loadFunc}
        hasMore={true || false}
        loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
        useWindow={false}
    >
        {items}
    </InfiniteScroll>
</div>
```

Custom parent element
You can define a custom parentNode element to base the scroll calulations on.

```
<div style="height:700px;overflow:auto;" ref={(ref) => this.scrollParentRef = ref}>
    <div>
        <InfiniteScroll
            pageStart={0}
            loadMore={loadFunc}
            hasMore={true || false}
            loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
            useWindow={false}
            getScrollParent={() => this.scrollParentRef}
        >
            {items}
        </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
</div>
```